# Javascript Object data isn't returning the correct value

Tags: javascript, object, extjs

I'm currently working on a Javascript project with Sencha and I'm facing a issue I can't even comprehend.

The problem is quite simple. Here's my code :

```
console.log("store : ");
console.log(store);
console.log("store length :");
console.log(store.data.length);
```

Here is what it returns :

```
store :
_data: Ext.apply.create.Class
_model: ()
_modelDefaults: Ext.Object.classify.objectClass
_params: Ext.Object.classify.objectClass
_proxy: Ext.apply.create.Class
_remoteFilter: false
_remoteGroup: false
_remoteSort: false
_storeId: "Indicator_Value"
_syncRemovedRecords: false
config: Ext.Object.classify.objectClass
data: Ext.apply.create.Class
     _autoFilter: true
    _autoSort: true
    _filterRoot: "data"
    _sortRoot: "data"
    all: Array[2]
    config: Ext.Object.classify.objectClass
    dirtyIndices: false
    getKey: (record)
    indices: Object
    initConfig: ()
    initialConfig: Object
    items: Array[2]
    keys: Array[2]
    length: 2
map: Object
__proto__: Ext.util.Collection#constructor
dateFirst: Mon Aug 31 2015 14:47:36 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))
dateLast: Mon Aug 31 2015 15:02:48 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été))
emptyNext: false
emptyPrevious: false
eventDispatcher: Ext.apply.create.Class
getEventDispatcher: ()
getId: ()
getObservableId: ()
getUniqueId: ()
graphType: 1
id: "myapp-store-indicator_value-1"
indicatorId: 262
initConfig: ()
initialConfig: Object
initialized: true
managedListeners: Object
observableId: "#myapp-store-indicator_value-1"
period: "H"
removed: Array[0]
titleIndicatorValue: "Duration in FTC"
usedSelectors: Array[1]
__proto__: Object


store length :
14
```

I just don't get it. store.data.length should return 2, but it keeps returning 14. Maybe there's something I just didn't understand about how stores work ?
Anyway, I'd really love some help, because I've been stuck on this for about 2 hours and I just can't see the end of it.

Thanks!

Comment: It appears as if the `length` value is returning the number of properties of the class stored in `store.data`.

Comment: Rename to .len instead

Comment: For arrays, `length` returns the number of array members. For functions, `length` returns the number of arguments the function expects in it's signature (this does not say anything about with how many parameters a function will be called). Apart from that, `length`is a reserved word. You don't use it for your own properties.

Comment: @connexo `length` is not a reserved keyword. That's like saying  that `toString` is a reserved keyword, it's not, it's just a property that applies to many objects. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Reserved_keywords_as_of_ECMAScript_6

Comment: @Dogson Ext version? Also, you need to show the  code you are using to create and load data into the store

Comment: @JuanMendes Anyway it's at least very bad practice to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just don't get it. store.data.length should return 2, but it keeps
>   returning 14.

That's easy. Where you see "2" you see the **current** count of the store because you are looking inside the store *object*. Where you see "14" you see the count **at the moment of writing it to the console**. Obviously, the count has changed since then for whatever reason!

That is easy to reproduce:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    data: ['foo', 'bar', 'aa', 'foo', 'bar', 'aa', 'foo', 'bar', 'aa', 'foo', 'bar', 'aa', 'bar', 'aa']
});
console.log(store);
console.log(store.data.length);
store.removeAt(0, 12);
```

Example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/s86

Comment: Yep, I was just figuring this out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to clarify, that happens because some debuggers evaluate the objects when you expand them in the console. Therefore, you get the value that is there at the moment you expand the `store.data` property. A typical solution is to call `JSON.stringify` on objects to make sure you get the current value. Note that in this case, you can't do it because `store` has cycles and can't be stringified...

Comment: @JuanMendes It looks like the reason the store count has changed is that the store has been filtered (which [does affect the count](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-getCount)). The presence of `data._filterRoot` and `data.all` tells that.

Answer (score 0):

`length` is a JavaScript property, so you shouldn't call your variable length.

If it's a build in class from this framework you are working with, try to figure out which length you want to get, and try this:

```
console.log(store.data.all.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`data` property](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-property-data) of the `Ext.data.Store` is not an array. It's a [`MixedCollection`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.util.MixedCollection). The MixedCollection does not have a `length` property.

The correct way to get the number or records in the store is to use

```
store.getCount()
```

Comment: He wants the .length he defined himself in the data class

Comment: @mplungjan Where does the OP say that they set the `.length` property themselves?

Comment: Look in his code, then look at what he displays!? `initialConfig: Object
    items: Array[2]
    keys: Array[2]
    length: 2`

Comment: @mplungjan That's result of console.log() , review original code and scroll to bottom of results.

Comment: Yes, I know. And his problem was console showed 2 when showing the object and 14 when he called console on the field later.

Comment: @mplungjan for properties in store.data ( Ext.apply.create.Class ) , it count as 14 from _autoFilter to length. I guess that's config of Ext.apply.create.Class.

Answer (score 0):

There is [data](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-property-data) property in data store , so you can read with this code :

```
store.data
```

The type of `store.data` is [Ext.util.MixedCollection](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.MixedCollection) , so you should count it with :

```
store.data.getCount()
```

As what you get with `console.log(store);` , you may find this code also works :

```
store.data.items.length
```